# Angularjs Radio button is not giving default value in json

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am implementing below radio button in my project. I am using angularjs tech.

Once I am loading the page on browser but value is not coming in JSON object.I already i given as attribute in the tag as checked="true".

when i am clicking once again on the radio button that time json object coming with value.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.internationalClient" ng-value="1">Yes

<input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.internationalClient" ng-value="0" ng-checked="true">No
```

json object before clicking radio button

{}

after click the radio button 
{
  "internationalClient": 0
}

So, ActuallyI want the value once i am loading the page on browser.

I want below result once i am opening my page on browser.
{
  "internationalClient": 0
}

Comment: Using [`ngChecked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) together with `ngModel` doesn't make any sense and could lead to unexpected results. You should set the default value in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the plnkr for your case. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/TPbYAr0h3BIXQ1RzuMrv?p=preview

Hope this helps.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-radio-input-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="radioExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.formModel = {
        internationalClient : 0
      }
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.internationalClient" ng-value="1">
    Yes
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.internationalClient" ng-value="0" ng-checked="true">
    No
  </label><br/>
  <tt>json = {{formModel}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a single form model (not repeated), just initialize in your controller:

```
$scope.formModel.internationalClient = $scope.formModel.internationalClient || 0;
```

It's shorthand for: "Set ..internationalClient to itself, unless ..internationalClient is null". That way, if it is an international client and the value is returned, this operation is idempotent.

If it's a form in ng-repeat, etc:

```
<form ng-init="formModel.internationalClient = 0">
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: Isn't this considered as a bad practice?

Comment: Updated comments, you are correct if it's a single form. I deal with a lot of repeated type forms so it was top of my. I added a better option as a first goal.

Comment: The first option is a shortcut saying if internationalClient isn't empty, set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript file you can set the default value

```
$scope.formModel.InternationalClient = 0;
```

Then have your radio buttons change the value